# How to print values from inside a theano function?

Tags: python, machine-learning, theano

I've recently moved from Matlab/C++ to theano and have the following function

```
train_model = theano.function([x_in, y_index],
                          classifier.cost,
                          updates=updates,
                          givens={
                              x: x_in,
                              y: y_in[y_index]})
```

and I'd like to print the values between 2 layers of the net in every iteration (for debugging, better control of the function etc.)
I've tried editing the function setting the classifier so that it prints (either using print() or theano.printing.Print/theano.pp()) and all I get is a single print while the model is being set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example `classifier.cost` is an expression, probably consisting of several other expressions building on the same input. You can turn any of those intermediate expressions into functions just as you are doing with `classifier.cost`, e.g.

```
f_first_layer = theano.function([x], first_layer)
```

You can then call and print the output of this function e.g. after every call to `train_model`. If you call it *before* `train_model` with the same params as you will call `train_model` with just after, then you will have the exact output of the layers as they will be evaluated by `train_model` (calling it after `train_model` will be different due to updating).

Comment: ok, so just to share knowledge, what i did was, for example:
f_first_layer = theano.function([x], [cost, print_val])
that gave me back the value I wanted to control, thanks for the answer

Comment: Thanks very much for the update! That looks like the most useful way to do it.